# What happened to options in rules in ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

This does not compile in ANTLR 4:

```
Number options { backtrack=true; }
  : (IntegerLiteral Range)=> IntegerLiteral { $type = IntegerLiteral; }
  | (FloatLiteral)=> FloatLiteral { $type = FloatLiteral; }
  | IntegerLiteral { $type = IntegerLiteral; }
  ;
```

because of backtrace= true... What happened to it?

WHat should I use in ANTLR 4 instread of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, there are no rule-level options in ANTLR v4. Note that `backtrack=true` is no longer needed since the new parsing algorithm has no need for backtracking. Also note that in ANTLR v3, `backtrack=true` was not valid inside lexer rules, only parser rules.

Comment: "... the new parsing algorithm has no need for backtracking": Hi, I am reading the book "Language Implementation Patterns". Pattern 5 is about backtracking and Pattern 6 is about memoization. Did you mean that the new parsing algorithm does not use these two patterns anymore? What is the new parsing algorithm? Could you please share with me some references? Thanks.

Comment: @hengxin see: https://groups.google.com/g/antlr-discussion/c/eNlRXD1M1nk?pli=1